# Inner product inequalities with a diagonal matrix defining the inner product

Tags: matrices, inequality

This question came about from analyzing symmetric positive definite bilinear form decompositions and trying to understand what conditions would ensure certain inequalities hold. Suppose we have 3 vectors $x,y,z \in {\mathbb R}^n$ ($n$ can be anything), that are orthogonal and equal length, and an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix $A$ with positive diagonal entries. Suppose further, $x^T A y \leq 0$ and $x^T A z \leq 0$, and furthermore $x^T A^{-1} y \geq 0$ and $x^T A^{-1} z \geq 0$.

Are there conditions, purely in terms of $x^T A y$ and $x^T A z$, to guarantee $x^T A^{-1} y > x^T A^{-1} z$? For example, maybe $x^T A y < x^T A z$? If that doesn't work, can someone construct a counter-example?

If no conditions in terms of  $x^T A y$ and $x^T A z$ can be found, are there at least some easy additional conditions that say, also involve the entries in $A$, to guarantee the desired inequality holds?

UPDATE: In dimension $8$, I believe I can now (with computer) find counter-examples to the claim that  $x^T A y < x^T A z$ is sufficient. This raises one more question, what is the minimal dimension where this condition is not sufficient?

Comment: I explored the specific case where $x=(-1,2,2)$, $y=(2,-1,2)$, and $z=(2,2,-1)$, and labeled the diagonal entries of $A$ as $1,b,c$ (scaling so that $a=1$ is wlog). The set of $(b,c)$ values satisfying your four inequalities is a football shape with endpoints at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. In this case at least, both $x^TAy<x^TAz$ and $x^TA^{-1}y > z^TA^{-1}z$ turned out to be the exact same region - the half of the football under the diagonal line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks, this really helps. I tried to find a counter-example in dimension 4 and couldn't find one, just like you in dimension 3, but I think I've found one in dimension 8, using randomized brute force search for $A$ and using $x,y,z$ that are all different patterns of four  $+1$ entries and four $-1$ entries that are orthogonal. I'll update the question with this and stipulate that a restriction on the dimension may be necessary.

Comment: Little late, but look at the paper "On the Theory of Equivalent Operators and Application to the Numerical Solution of Uniformly Elliptic Partial Differential Equations"